# Oracle backup and recovery tablespace

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, tablespace

In Oracle 11.2 DB I have: 
 - **transaction** table in tablespace users and
 
 - **transaction_bkp** table in **trans_bkp** tablespace

Transaction table holds data for 1 month and transaction_bkp should hold data as long as possible.

Problem is that trans_bkp tablespace becomes full after 6 months.

Idea to resolve this problem is to **backup trans_bkp tablespace every month and then truncate table transaction_bkp.**

How to do this backup? 
If customer will need some specific data in past how can I delivery them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of RMAN and define your retention policy.

1. Backup tablespace trans_pkp using something like (for as long as you like to keep it)

   BACKUP TABLESPACE TRANS_BKP KEEP FOREVER NOLOGS TAG 'FIRSTHALF2014;
2. Truncate table transition_bkp

Restore:

- Make use of TSPITR (Automatic Tablespace Point-in-Time Recovery)
- Utilize RMAN duplicate from backup and *set until time*

You might want to use a naming convention for the tablespace. 
Like TRANS_BKP_01_2014, TRANS_BKP_02_2014, etc...

Comment: Tnx. What do you think about this solution compared to the one above?

1. Export transaction_bkp with expdp 
2. copy exported file of that table to backup location
3. truncate table transaction_bkp?